# =COUNTIF Cells that aren't adjacent - Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to count selected cells if the cell contains anything. I can't get it to work with the `=COUNTIF` formula:

```
=COUNTIF(E20,I20,M20,Q20,E23,I23,M23,Q23, "<>")
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Create an array for all the cells you want to count.

```
=COUNTIF({E20,I20,M20,Q20,E23,I23,M23,Q23}, "<>")
```

See if that works?

Comment: Awesome, learned something new again, thnx!

Answer (score 2):

A different way would be to use `QUERY()` like so:

```
=COUNTA(QUERY(E20:Q23,"Select E,I,M,Q skipping 3"))
```

Comment: Thnx for sharing an alternative way!